# Why does my scearch ber button not have the magnifying glass?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

**Hi there**,
I'm adding a search bar to my website, but when it add the
magnifying glass from font awesome, it doesn't show.
I only included the css for the search bar since I have
everything else set up nicely
What is the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>OnTop Servers</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="topnav">
        <div class="topnav-right">
        <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="search.html">Search</a>
        <a href="servers.html">Servers</a>
        </div>
         <h2 class="title">
            OnTop Servers
        </h2>
    </nav>
    <center>
        <div class="welcome">
            <div class="centered-text">
                <div class="welcome-body-inner">
                <h2 class="head">
                    DISCOVER
                    <span class="discord-logo">discord1</span>
                    SERVERS
                </h2>
                <h3 class="body">
                    Find amazing servers to interact with and make friends
                </h3>
                  <div class="search-box">
                      <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Search..">
                      <a class="search-btn" href="">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                      </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
```

Heres is the css for the search bar:

```
.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 35%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #2c2c2c;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-btn {
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c2c2c;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: You didn't show us how you're loading FontAwesome.

Comment: I suspect you're not actually loading FontAwesome. It's not in your HTML. Why don't you make a minimal reproducible example, either in a code snippet or in a similar tool like JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with the code is that you did not include the Font Awesome Files or CDN or Icons to be exact. You have to fetch it from somewhere like Downloading the Font Awesome Icon or Simply use the CDN (Recommended)

I am giving you the CDN of font awesome and put this line of code in the `<head>` part of the code

The CDN is: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />` or you can follow a tutorial in youtube and download those Icons

For Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />
    <title>OnTop Servers</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="topnav">
        <div class="topnav-right">
        <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="search.html">Search</a>
        <a href="servers.html">Servers</a>
        </div>
         <h2 class="title">
            OnTop Servers
        </h2>
    </nav>
    <center>
        <div class="welcome">
            <div class="centered-text">
                <div class="welcome-body-inner">
                <h2 class="head">
                    DISCOVER
                    <span class="discord-logo">discord1</span>
                    SERVERS
                </h2>
                <h3 class="body">
                    Find amazing servers to interact with and make friends
                </h3>
                  <div class="search-box">
                      <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Search..">
                      <a class="search-btn" href="">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                      </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
```

Hope you have a great day!